# Does any regular surface have a sequence of inscribed polyhedra whose surface area arbitrarily exceeds the area of the surface?

Tags: area, surfaces, polyhedra, triangulation

The [Schwartz lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lantern) is a family of sequences of [noble polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_polyhedron) inscribed within a cylinder that have the counterintuitive property that, as the number of vertices grows larger, the total surface area of the inscribed polyhedra can approach any value  (including infinity) that is greater than or equal to the surface area $2\pi r h$ of the circumscribing cylinder.

A cylinder seems to me to be a pretty non-pathological surface, and noble polyhedra seem pretty "nice" and non-pathological as well (as opposed to, say, something weird like the Alexander horned sphere where you could imagine the vertices "bunching up" infinitely faster than average at certain points). If this phenomenon can happen for a surface as simple as a cylinder, then it seems to me that it can probably happen for any regular surface. Is the following conjecture generalizing the Schwarz lantern construction correct?

> For any regular surface, there exists a sequence of inscribed polyhedra with an increasing number of vertices whose total surface area approaches any value (including infinity) greater than or equal to the area of the surface.

I also conjecture that as long as the vertices cover every part of the surface with ever-increasing density, then the total surface area of a sequence of inscribed polyhedra can't approach any value less than the surface area of the circumscribing surface. I'm not sure how to make that claim completely rigorous, but I'd be interested if anyone could comment on that conjecture as well.

Comment: Clearly not true for the flat plane, although whether you consider a tiling as a polyhedron is moot. Appears to be true for any curved surface, though I'd have to think about negative Gaussian curvature in general.

Comment: If there is any curvature at all, then you can take a geodesic curve on the surface, and inscribe in the curve a little triangle which is perpendicular to the surface (and very obtuse). It should be possible to make an arbitrary number of such triangles in a small area of the surface.

Comment: I mean, can't you just repeat the Schwarz lantern construction locally?